# Showing hiding debug content via cookie test, is it a best practice?

Tags: laravel, debugging, cookies, frameworks

As environment example working with Laravel...

I'm feeling the need to have debug layers
and have the chance to reveal backend info on the web UI

So for example how are set some env variables under some circumstances, or what endpoints is my frontend app calling...

What I was thinking is to create a conditional template inclusion for a debug template partial to show some debug vars e.g.:

```
    @includeWhen(isset($_COOKIE['debug'], 'partials.debug-layer')
```

as you might noticed above the strategy is to set (and maybe verify if equal to a secret value && $_COOKIE['debug']==='secret') in the current client a cookie to be able to reveal that debug layer partial.

The concern is about be sure that someone external might not in some way find out this and reveal this information.
Not going to display sensitive info (like passwords or usernames) but even thought, will be better if they don't see it.

Do you have some ideas or better setup for such situation and debugging?

Comment: I like your idea. You maybe could implement a session variable if the user was authenticated and work with the variable in server side. Maybe you can enable a button so the could change this parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Well Session was another option but, Id like to be free from being auth to show hide this debug info.

Comment: So you could make a post for eg. /mysystem.com/debug?secret=mysecretcode&status=1. And the server side you could validate the secret, and maybe you could validate the remote IP address to.

Comment: Ip address filtering is something that doesn't add flexibility and do not improve the use case.

Comment: So, use a secret phrase maybe sending in Authentication header.